# style custom checkbox label appearance

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the checked mode to look like the hover mode of my custom checkbox.
I realized the problem is with the label but i don't succeed with styling it to fit the whole wrapper div.

```html
<div class="ck-btn">
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox"><span>test</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

this is my css:

```css
.ck-btn {
    padding: .3rem 1.8rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.6),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185,0.26);
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #b183ce;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #b183ce;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.ck-btn:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #b183ce, #56dac2);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.ck-btn label {
    float: left;
    width: 4em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ck-btn label span {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    border-radius: 45px;
    display: block;
}

.ck-btn label input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
}

.ck-btn input:checked + span {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #b183ce, #56dac2);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: I misread your question @Raz _ Did some more research and found this that might be useful >>> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not want to change your code too much but if you just remove `float: left;` from label styles everything will align, for the most part. You will still need tinker around the padding for the div or overflow `span` to fill the div when checkbox is checked.

Below is updated example:

```css
.ck-btn {
    padding: .3rem 1.8rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.6),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185,0.26);
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #b183ce;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #b183ce;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.ck-btn:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #b183ce, #56dac2);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.ck-btn label {    
    width: 4em;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.ck-btn label span {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    border-radius: 45px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

.ck-btn label input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
}

.ck-btn input:checked + span {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #b183ce, #56dac2);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="ck-btn">
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox"><span>test</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

didn't get your question properly but if you wanting to make label `test` as wide as you hover div. add `width: 100%` to `.ck-btn label{}`.

let me know if its something else you want